# Extract Page Intro Info with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Beautiful Soup and I am trying to extract the information that appears on a page. This info is contained in the div class="_50f3", and depending on the user it can contain multiple info (studies, studied, works, worked, lives, etc). So, far I have managed though the following code to parse the div classes, but I don't know how to extract the information I want from that..

```
table = soup.findAll('div', {'class': '_50f3'})

[<div class="_50f3">Lives in <a class="profileLink" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=114148045261892" href="/Fort-Worth-Texas/114148045261892?ref=br_rs">Fort Worth, Texas</a></div>,
 <div class="_50f3">From <a class="profileLink" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=111762725508574" href="/Dallas-Texas/111762725508574?ref=br_rs">Dallas, Texas</a></div>]
```

For example, in the above I would like to store "Lives in" : "Fort Worth, Texas" and "From": "Dallas, Texas". But in the most general case I would like to store whatever info there is in there.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case this is just [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) you need - it would construct a single element text string recursively going through the child nodes:

```
table = soup.find_all('div', {'class': '_50f3'})
print([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in table])
```

---

But, you can also extract the labels and values separately:

```
d = {}
for item in table:
    label = item.find(text=True)
    value = label.next_sibling

    d[label.strip()] = value.get_text()

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'From': 'Dallas, Texas', 'Lives in': 'Fort Worth, Texas'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(table)):
    print(table[i].text)
```

Should Work